# How to access variables from outside the interface

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, interface

I have an interface that asks for some inputs I want to access the inputs from the outside interface loop but can't figure out how he's what I have so far.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

s_n = Entry(root)
n_o_p = Entry(root)
s_t = Entry(root)
f_n = Entry(root)
c = Entry(root)

s_n.insert(0,"Enter Subreddit name")
n_o_p.insert(1,"Enter number of posts")
s_t.insert(2,"Enter search type")
f_n.insert(3,"Enter flair tpye")
c.insert(4,"Enter amount of comments")


s_n.pack()
n_o_p.pack()
s_t.pack()
f_n.pack()
c.pack()

def myclick():
    global s_n
    global n_o_p
    global s_t
    global f_n
    global c

myButton = Button(root, text="Enter: ", command=myclick)
myButton.pack()


root.mainloop()

#print (s_n)
#print (s_n.get())
```

I tried making the variables global but when I print the variable I just get `!entry`.

Comment: Do you want to access the user input in the entries after the GUI is closed?

Comment: yes i do i need that

Answer (score 1):

You can acces your variables with that code below:

```py
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

s_n = Entry(root)
n_o_p = Entry(root)
s_t = Entry(root)
f_n = Entry(root)
c = Entry(root)

s_n.insert(0,"Enter Subreddit name")
n_o_p.insert(1,"Enter number of posts")
s_t.insert(2,"Enter search type")
f_n.insert(3,"Enter flair tpye")
c.insert(4,"Enter amount of comments")


s_n.pack()
n_o_p.pack()
s_t.pack()
f_n.pack()
c.pack()


def myclick():
    global s_n
    s_n = s_n.get()


myButton = Button(root, text="Enter: ", command=myclick)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()


print(s_n)
```

Comment: I did try that but it says invalid syntax

Comment: I cant seem to use .get() outside of the interface loop[

Comment: I created a varibale to get it without `.get()`.   
`s_n = s_n.get()` just call the `s_n` like a global varibale.

Comment: local variable 's_n' referenced before assignment

Comment: It works for me. Did you click to button? https://imgur.com/a/RU3wcSv

Comment: I think it would be better not to override the variable `s_n` in `myclick()`, that is to use a different name for variable that will contain the content of the entry

Comment: yep just has the referenced before assignment error

Comment: I did try using a new variable name (s) but then when I called it (s) NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: What do yo uthink `root.protocol(myclick)` is going to do? Adding that code does absolutely nothing to solve the issue.

Comment: I deleted `root.protocol(myclick)` from code. I could not understand why I use it. Sorry about it.